# How to remove a specific geofence after triggering it

Tags: android, kotlin, geofencing

Scenario: The below mentioned code snippet shows a BroadcastReciver whose work is to start a service whenever the added geonfence is entered. A JobIntentService is then initiated which does some operation with the passed on string, and then triggers notification with the data.

What needs to be done: I want that, among many other added geofences, when a specific geofence is triggered, it should be removed to prevent from retriggering.

Question: How to implement this in above mentioned scenario?

Below is the screenshot for reference

```
class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == ACTION_GEOFENCE_EVENT) {

            val geoFencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent)

            if (geoFencingEvent.hasError()) {
                Timber.i("Error while activating Geofencing: ${geoFencingEvent.errorCode}")
                return
            } else {

                val geoFenceTransition = geoFencingEvent.geofenceTransition

                if (geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {
                    val geofenceId = geoFencingEvent.triggeringGeofences[0].requestId

                    val jobIntent = Intent(context, GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService::class.java)
                        .putExtra("REMINDER_ID", geofenceId)
                    GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService.enqueueWork(context, jobIntent)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```